# Are there any fast 256 bit decoders for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am currently working on a 256 byte RAM. To access one address i have to build a decoder. My current decoder is a big block of AND-Gates with redstonetorches to check each combination. Are there any faster ways?

Current version of my decoder:

[image: Decoder with labels]

Comment: [Using big blocks of AND gates is pretty much unavoidable.](http://cpuville.com/decoder.htm) That's why computers needed integrated circuits to get smaller and faster. ;)

Comment: is this guy seriously building a real life computer... IN MINECRAFT?

Comment: @Ender What if I told you, that you can build a computer/system in Minecraft?!

Comment: @Ender [A *lot* of people build CPUs or parts thereof in Minecraft. :)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGkkyKZVzug)

Comment: Their goal is to run Minecraft in Minecraft.

Comment: Currently it only supports ping pong (written in a language like ASM) :)

Comment: Back to the original question: How you need to output your data would probably always be very specific to what that data is going to be used for... You don't always need 256 bits, but when you do - those memory cells are dedicated to that use and the output is custom to that purpose. However, that being said I'm sure that the minified and/or/nor gates are the best available in vanilla.

Comment: If you're looking for data transfer mechanisms, perhaps try one of these vids: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_V8S4kZWjY http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DM-V_17AtAI

Comment: @Ender First reaction when I saw that screen shot... O M G... some people have way too much time on their hands.

Comment: Just how fast, is fast?  Without knowing just how fast you want it, there are many answers.  I'm happy with a system I've made, but it takes a second or two for writing/reading (12 bit addressing), but it may also be possible to have it almost instant (using instant wire/smaller addressing)

Comment: Maybe I meant faster or easier than my current approach. Too long ago

Comment: How long does it currently take?

Comment: Please have a look at the date of the question

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably not the speed of and gates, they are usually just a few ticks.
I'd rather guess that the problem is that you set them up in a way that the decoder is sending the signal to the and gates one after another, instead of all at the same time.

Your screenshot doesn't relly show much about the design you used, however there are a **lot** of decoders out there. (really just google a bit and you'll find tons)

I've built one for you that is instant on the rising edge (but takes inverted input):

This one uses 3 bits, but can be expanded if required. The torches you see in front take an extra tick, but may be required depending on your design. The input is 000 so the far right one is selected.

[image: decoder]
In this design, a redstone block with dust on it is used for a 0, a block with a torch is used for a 1. (from right to left: 000, 001, 010)

The pistons in the middle (or the odd ones) have an extra piston on top so they're updated by the redstone above:
[image: decoder]

Some more screenshots:
[image: decoder]
[image: decoder]

Answer (score 0):

As SevenSidedDie said in the comments, you pretty much cannot avoid using AND gates for decoders.

There is a way though: Use **Command Blocks**.

With the new `setblock` features you can set redstone blocks. These don't have the delay that redstone repeaters / torches have, so your redstone signals can travel large distances faster.

This is not a nice fix, because the point of building a redstone computer (is for me at least) to do it *without* any command blocks. But maybe this will still help.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65g8a_Hv3ZU) could help? In the current design it is set as ROM but I think you could easily change that with some block replacers

Comment: Could you explain what happens in the video you linked? Since not everyone has the time/patience to watch a youtube video for a *possible* solution.